# Firebase rules to fix 'Missing or insufficient permissions' error when accessing user data with NextAuth

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, next.js, firebase-security, next-auth

I'm using NextAuth and Firebase to retrieve a user's data but I'm encountering the following error when I try to run this function:

> Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

```js
async function getBalance(uid) {
  const userRef = doc(db, "users", uid);
  const userDoc = await getDoc(userRef);

  if (userDoc.exists()) {
    const { tokens } = userDoc.data();
    return tokens;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

How do I set the rules in Firebase to fix this error? Here are my configuration files:

```js
import { getApps } from "firebase-admin/app";
import admin from "firebase-admin";

const serviceAccount = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY);

if (!getApps().length) {
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  });
}

const adminDb = admin.firestore();
const adminAuth = admin.auth();

export { adminDb, adminAuth };
```

```js
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getApps, initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_APIKEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASEURL,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECTID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APPID,
  measurementId: process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENTID,
};

const app = getApps().length ? getApp() : initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export { db };
```

This is how my database is structured:

```
/users/email@example.com/chats/UN3XookDLjiJvqsW7GPG/messages/2gKLNAKDGiNWy2TvcFWq
```

In this case, `email@example.com` is the `uid`.

This is my current Firebase rules:

```lua
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      
      match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I was able to run the function with these testing rules:

```lua
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2023, 4, 19);
    }
  }
}
```

What do I need to change in my Firebase rules to allow access to user data?

Comment: How is your `uid` initialized? That has to be the UID of the current user signed into Firebase Authentication, otherwise it doesn't match the `request.auth.uid` that your rules requires it to.

Comment: The `uid` is from Next Auth `session.user.email` like in this code:
```
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (session?.user?.email) {
      (async () => {
        const balance = await getBalance(session.user.email);
        setBalance(balance);
      })();
    }
  }, [session]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `request.auth` in your Firestore security rules is populated by Firebase automatically, but only when a user signs in with Firebase Authentication.

Since you're not signing in to Firebase Authentication, the `request.auth` won't be populated and your rules check will reject all access.

To solve this, you'll want to take the information of the user signed into Next Auth and use that to also sign in to Firebase. This flow is described in the documentation on [custom sign-in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth) and [minting custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens), so I recommend following those to address the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, Frank! I managed to make it work after three days. I've posted my code based on your answer. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

This is the code that works for me (based on the docs Frank van Puffelen suggested).

Put this where you handle user sign in:

```js
import { auth, db } from "../firebase/firebase";
import { signInWithCustomToken } from "firebase/auth";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";

  const { data: session } = useSession();

  const signInWithFirebase = async (session) => {
    const response = await fetch("/api/createCustomToken", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ user: session.user }),
    });

    const customToken = await response.json();

    signInWithCustomToken(auth, customToken.token)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        const user = userCredential.user;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        // ...
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (session) {
      signInWithFirebase(session);
    }
  }, [session]);
```

firebaseAdmin.js

```js
import admin from "firebase-admin";

const serviceAccount = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY);
if (!admin.apps.length) {
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  });
}

const adminDb = admin.firestore();
const adminAuth = admin.auth();

export { adminDb, adminAuth };
```

firebase.js

```js
import { getApp, getApps, initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_APIKEY,
authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN,
databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASEURL,
projectId: process.env.PROJECTID,
storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET,
messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APPID,
measurementId: process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENTID,
};

const app = getApps().length ? getApp() : initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const auth = getAuth(app);
export { db, auth };
```

pages/api/createCustomToken.js

```js
import { adminAuth } from "@/firebase/firebaseAdmin";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method !== "POST") {
    res.status(405).json({ message: "Method not allowed" });
    return;
  }

  const { user } = req.body;

  const uid = user.email;

  try {
    const customToken = await adminAuth.createCustomToken(uid);

    res.status(200).json({ token: customToken });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error creating custom token:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Error creating custom token" });
  }
}
```

Please note that this code is working for me, and you might need to make changes to adapt it to your own specific use case.

Comment: Isn't this going to create additional latency now that the user needs to login with a custom token everytime a request is sent?