# Firebase Security Rules for NextAuth

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, next-auth

I am using Firebase + NextJS where I set up the authentication with NextAuth and FirestoreAdapter. I am using the following allow-all rules for debugging and all of my intended features are working perfectly.

```py
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true
    }
  }
}
```

However, I know this is a huge security issue when I push the code to production and wish to add more specific rules so only document owners can read and write the data. I have tried this solution from [this github issue](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/3850) with no success.

```py
match /store/{userId}/{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.token.id == userId && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/tokens/$(request.auth.uid)/sessions/$(request.auth.token.sessionToken));
}
```

I believe the main issue comes from the way nextAuth and FirestoreAdapter is interacting with my Firestore database. When I create a new document using the following code, it creates the document in “users → session.user.id → chats → document” as per the screenshot below, but the User UID and session.user.id is not the same which is why I think the code above is not working.

Is there a proper way to set up security rules so DB read/write is only allowed when
session.user.id == chatDoc.userId?

[image]

Create New Draft

```py
const createNewDraft = async () => {
      const doc = await addDoc(
        collection(db, "users", session?.user?.id!, "drafts"),
        {
          userId: session?.user?.id!,
          createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
        }
      );
 };
```

[…nextAuth].ts

```py
import { FirestoreAdapter } from "@next-auth/firebase-adapter";
import { GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithCredential } from "firebase/auth";
import { cert } from "firebase-admin/app";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import "firebase/firestore";

import { fbAuth } from "../../../../firebase";

const sa = JSON.parse(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_SERVICE_KEY);

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
      try {
        const googleCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          account?.id_token
        );
        const userCredential = await signInWithCredential(
          fbAuth,
          googleCredential
        ).catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
          return false;
        });
        return !!userCredential;
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return false;
      }
    },
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
      if (session?.user) {
        session.user.id = token.sub;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  adapter: FirestoreAdapter({
    credential: cert({
      projectId: sa.project_id,
      clientEmail: sa.client_email,
      privateKey: sa.private_key,
    }),
  }),
};
export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

Comment: What is `sessionToken`? You're not showing where that gets set in the user's custom claims. Without that, the rule will always reject.

Comment: Is it not possible to implement firestore security rules with Next Auth Firebase adapter as [@auth/firebase-adapter](https://authjs.dev/reference/adapter/firebase#installation) uses firebase admin sdk to initialize the firestore DB and firebase admin sdk bypass all cloud firestore security rules.check this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) & stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57761870/18265638)

Comment: @SathiAiswarya That means it should work technically with just rejecting everything by using the following rule, right? Both documents don't seem to work in my case. Are there any other recommendations you suggest?
```
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if false;
}
```

Comment: Where you able to find a solution?  Please share what you did. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue, because there is no way to pass the user session to the Firebase security rule for obvious security reason.

After some digging, I found 2 possible solutions.

(1) Structure all database CRUD access from server side using the Firebase Admin SDK, because the Firebase admin bypass all security rules, you can then set database read and write to false to protect all other access. This structure is now possible with NextJS [app router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app) where server component by default and using [server actions](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/server-actions) to perform server side operations on client components.

(2) Use Firebase Auth's `signInWithCustomToken()` method to signin to Firebase Auth by passing the user session from NextAuth. This require 2 extra steps from the existing NextAuth setup.

Create a custom token using Firebase admin's `createCustomToken()` from the API route (app router example).

```js
// api/createCustomToken/route.js

import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { adminAuth } from "@/firebase/firebaseAdmin";

export async function POST(req, res) {
  if (req.method !== "POST") {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "Method not allowed" },
      { status: 405 }
    );
  }

  const { user } = await req.json();

  try {
    const customToken = await adminAuth.createCustomToken(user.id);
    return NextResponse.json({ token: customToken }, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "Error creating custom token" },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}
```

Once obtained the custom token, then sign in to Firebase Auth using `signInWithCustomToken()` on the client side.

```js
const { data: session, status } = useSession();

const signInWithFirebase = async (user) => {
  const response = await fetch("/api/createCustomToken", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ user }),
  });

  const customToken = await response.json();

  signInWithCustomToken(auth, customToken.token)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      const user = userCredential.user;
      console.log(user);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};

useEffect(() => {
  if (!session) return;

  signInWithFirebase(session.user);
}, [session]);
```

Once the user session is registered with Firebase, your database security rules should work as expected.

You can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75963110/firebase-rules-to-fix-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-error-when-accessing) for further reading.